# How to Disable Chrome File menu bar from auto-hiding

Tags: google-chrome, menu-bar, macos

Is there a way to preserve the bar at the top of Chrome that has File, Edit, View, History etc, without it auto-hiding? I find this extremely annoying that my window size changes with this auto-hide. I'd like to keep those menu items visible at all times.

"Automatically hide & show the menu bar" is not enabled in System Preferences.

running  OSX 10.13.6 with Chrome build 96.0.4664.110

Answer (score 2):

Don't use fullscreen, maximise instead.
Cmd/double-click any window edge or corner, when you can see the double arrows [not the single arrow].
[Opt-clicking the green dot will not always fully maximise]